# No puedo imprimir en consola NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, class, print, console

Hola una pequeña duda: ¿Por qué no me sale en consola las impresiones?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En este caso trata de limpiar (Clean) y construir tu proyecto nuevamente (Build), en las últimas versiones de `Netbeans` esto soluciona el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cerré cuando hice la pregunta y ahora al abrir para hacer lo que sugieres si me imprime en consola.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que se vuelve a construir el proyecto, es una falla que ocurre no muy comunmente en Netbeans.